# Confusion in -0x20(%ebp)

Tags: assembly

I recently self learn computer system. I do not understand following codes from binary bomb lab phase 2. I typed 1 2 3 4 5 6 as inputs

What does those lanes do? 
how does this -0x20 come from? What is it purpose?

```
0x08048bab <+7>:    lea    -0x20(%ebp),%eax
0x08048bae <+10>:   mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
```

Those codes come from

```
Dump of assembler code for function phase_2:

0x08048ba4 <+0>:    push   %ebp
0x08048ba5 <+1>:    mov    %esp,%ebp
0x08048ba7 <+3>:    push   %ebx
0x08048ba8 <+4>:    sub    $0x34,%esp
0x08048bab <+7>:    lea    -0x20(%ebp),%eax
0x08048bae <+10>:   mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
0x08048bb2 <+14>:   mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x08048bb5 <+17>:   mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x08048bb8 <+20>:   call   0x804928d <read_six_numbers>
0x08048bbd <+25>:   cmpl   $0x0,-0x20(%ebp)
0x08048bc1 <+29>:   jns    0x8048be3 <phase_2+63>
0x08048bc3 <+31>:   call   0x804924b <explode_bomb>
0x08048bc8 <+36>:   jmp    0x8048be3 <phase_2+63>
0x08048bca <+38>:   mov    %ebx,%eax
0x08048bcc <+40>:   add    -0x24(%ebp,%ebx,4),%eax
0x08048bd0 <+44>:   cmp    %eax,-0x20(%ebp,%ebx,4)
0x08048bd4 <+48>:   je     0x8048bdb <phase_2+55>
0x08048bd6 <+50>:   call   0x804924b <explode_bomb>
0x08048bdb <+55>:   inc    %ebx
0x08048bdc <+56>:   cmp    $0x6,%ebx
0x08048bdf <+59>:   jne    0x8048bca <phase_2+38>
0x08048be1 <+61>:   jmp    0x8048bea <phase_2+70>
```

2.

I feel

```
mov 0xc(%ebp),%eax
```

is getting inputs.

I tried x /s $ebp+oxc, it prints this string \350\366\377\277\b\367\377\277>\223\004\b{\246\004\b.
what is that? I really had hard time to understand what is this doing? I tried to print out value in every memory address, but it did not help.

When I tried to print out x /d $eax before cmp    $0x5,%eax,  it shows  Cannot access memory at address 0x0.

```
 Dump of assembler code for function read_six_numbers:
0x0804928d <+0>:    push   %ebp
0x0804928e <+1>:    mov    %esp,%ebp
0x08049290 <+3>:    sub    $0x28,%esp
0x08049293 <+6>:    mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x08049296 <+9>:    lea    0x14(%eax),%edx
0x08049299 <+12>:   mov    %edx,0x1c(%esp)
0x0804929d <+16>:   lea    0x10(%eax),%edx
0x080492a0 <+19>:   mov    %edx,0x18(%esp)
0x080492a4 <+23>:   lea    0xc(%eax),%edx
0x080492a7 <+26>:   mov    %edx,0x14(%esp)
0x080492ab <+30>:   lea    0x8(%eax),%edx
0x080492ae <+33>:   mov    %edx,0x10(%esp)
0x080492b2 <+37>:   lea    0x4(%eax),%edx
0x080492b5 <+40>:   mov    %edx,0xc(%esp)
0x080492b9 <+44>:   mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
0x080492bd <+48>:   movl   $0x804a64b,0x4(%esp)
0x080492c5 <+56>:   mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x080492c8 <+59>:   mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x080492cb <+62>:   call   0x8048860 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
0x080492d0 <+67>:   cmp    $0x5,%eax
0x080492d3 <+70>:   jg     0x80492da <read_six_numbers+77>
0x080492d5 <+72>:   call   0x804924b <explode_bomb>
```

Comment: The `sub  $0x34,%esp` instruction creates some scratch space on the stack for things like local variables.  The `lea -0x20(%ebp),%eax` instruction loads the address of a location in this scratch space into `eax`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael said, the `sub $0x34,%esp` creates space for local variables. Since `mov %esp,%ebp` copied `%esp` to `%ebp` previously, this allocated space can also be addressed relative to `%ebp` ranging from `%ebp-0x34` up to `%ebp`. `%ebp-0x20` is the address of a local variable, in this case it's the base address of an array of integers of size 6 (ie. `int numbers[6];`) This address is loaded into `%eax` and subsequently written to the stack:

```
0x08048bab <+7>:    lea    -0x20(%ebp),%eax
0x08048bae <+10>:   mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
```

The applicable calling convention specifies that arguments shall be passed on the stack. As such, this is passing the address as the second argument to the following function call. The first is at `%esp`:

```
0x08048bb2 <+14>:   mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x08048bb5 <+17>:   mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x08048bb8 <+20>:   call   0x804928d <read_six_numbers>
```

Note that incoming arguments to the current function are also on the stack, and can be addressed using positive offsets from `%ebp`, starting from 8. As such, the above code passes the first incoming argument as first argument to `read_six_numbers`. Putting it all together, the code so far may look something like this:

```
void phase_2(char* text)
{
    int numbers[6];
    read_six_numbers(text, numbers);
    ...
}
```

Looking at `read_six_numbers` we can see that it fetches the incoming arguments and creates a bunch of outgoing arguments for `sscanf`:

```
void read_six_numbers(char* text, int* numbers)
{
    if (sscanf(text, "%d %d %d %d %d %d", numbers, numbers + 1,
            numbers + 2, numbers + 3, numbers + 4, numbers + 5) != 6)
        explode_bomb();
}
```

I trust you can see how this is done in the assembly code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see,  -0x20(%ebp) is not reading in any inputs, it just assign a pointer for int[6] for read_six_numbers function.  Thank you so much, I spent almost entire night try to understand what is going on there. For my second question,  cmp    $0x5,%eax, $eax should be return value for sscanf function. Why I could not print out %eax? I tried  x /s $eax, it shows <Address 0x0 out of bounds> and  x /d $eax, it also shows Cannot access memory at address 0x0. I expect it should print out 6.

Comment: `x` is for examining memory, but eax at that point is just a number. You can use the `p(rint)` command for that, ie. `p $eax`.

Answer (score 0):

EBP points to the "bottom" of the stack frame. So when you need to put stuff into the the stack, you address it by subtracting from EBP.

So, in your example, it takes the address of "EBP - 0x20" and stores the result in EAX.